# Bat File that will read the server file and then restart based on output of server file

Tags: windows, batch-file

So far I've been trying to make a continuous .bat file that will start the server file, read every line that comes down and if the response "Server has become unresponsive" then the bat will close the file and re-open(this needs to be done every hour or so and I'm not always at the computer)

I do believe this is the correct code but I need to double check with some tech-savy minds to see if it's correct.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`"findstr rust_server/n ^^ "`) do (
    set "myVar=%%A"
    call :processLine myVar
)
goto :eof

:processLine

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=!%1!"
set "line=!line:*:=!"
echo(!line!

Find /I /V "Unresponsive for 10" 
taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq rust_server*"
start /d "C:\Rust Server" rust_server.exe

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This script will do things - Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off
Title SERVER RESTARTER (place with your rust_server exe)
color 1f
SET n=0
:Loop
SET /A n=n+1
echo Server Restarter
echo -----Restart Server Batch VERSION-----
taskkill /IM rust_server.exe
echo Opening rust_server.exe server again
rust_server.exe
if %n% EQU 60 (
exit
) Else if %n% LEQ 24 (
Goto Loop
```